# PerformanceCounter Category does not exist even though it exists

Tags: c#, windows, performance, azure, monitoring

I have an Azure Web Role and a separate Windows Service running on my IIS machine. Web role creates a custom performance counter category and two counters. I am trying to read the performance counters from my Windows Service. Even though `PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName)` returns `true`, `GetCounters` method throws an exception saying `Category does not exist` (see update).

```
if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName))
{
    try
    {
        // Get the existing category and counters
        PerformanceCounterCategory existingCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory(categoryName);
        counters = existingCategory.GetCounters();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to read the performance category {0}. Exception: {1}", categoryName, e.Message);
    }
}
```

Windows service runs as a local system service, so it should have privileges I think. In fact, I am able to see performance category and counters via Visual Studio's Server Explorer.

If category doesn't exist, I should expect `PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName)` to fail in the first place, right?

UPDATES

- I saw `GetCounters` method throw `InvalidOperationException` with message `Could not Read Category Index: {some index here}.` too.
- [Similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cb547e2-d13e-4ede-b042-38627675e321/trying-to-read-performancecounter-getting-could-not-read-category-index-) posted on msdn forums
- The same process is able to read the counters fine.

Answer (score 4):

We ran into the same issue.
It was something wrong with whole PerformanceCounters in actual WindowsInstance.
We resolved it by this CMD command (run as Admin):

```
lodctr /R
```

It rebuilt PerformanceCounters from some backup store.

If it does not resolve your issue, you can try this (again CMD with Admin rights):

```
Winmgmt /resyncperf 
Net stop winmgmt /y 
Net start winmgmt
```

Source: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/43987